# Does this patent apply to the USA

Tags: applicable

Does this patent apply to the USA "CN203725858 U"?

International Classification    B23C3/34, B23Q5/34

I'm starting a preliminary patent search, how can I tell if patents apply to the USA.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a Chinese patent, which can't apply in the US. US patents apply in the US.

The related question, then, is whether there's a US patent that corresponds to the one you're citing. A quick search doesn't turn up any, at least that's currently granted (nor a published application)--but given the time it frequently takes for a US patent to issue, it could have been applied for, and not issued yet (in fact, if they applied for a US patent 1 year after the Chinese patent issued (a common practice) it would be quite unexpected for the US patent to have issued already.

As for the general question of how to tell if a patent applies in the US, that's fairly simple: if it's a US patent, it applies in the US. Otherwise, it doesn't.

There is a [world patent office](http://www.wipo.int/pct/en/), but it doesn't actually grant patents that apply worldwide, or anything like that. Rather, it provides a way to (somewhat) more easily apply for a patent in each of the countries that participates in the patent cooperation treaty (currently 148 countries).

I should probably add that there is also a [European Patent Office](https://www.epo.org/index.html), which will (eventually, at least in theory) issue patents that apply to the entirety of the European Union (currently 40 countries). Unlike the world patent office, the EPO is supposed to eventually directly issue a single patent that should apply equally throughout all of Europe (but currently most European countries still have their own patent offices, and this unified patent for all of Europe remains a future possibility). The agreements to do this have been signed, but at least as I write this, it hasn't been implemented yet. It's hard to be sure when it will actually happen.

Comment: Although you probably know this, and were just glossing over it, the EPO doesn't currently issue a single patent that applies throughout Europe. The European patent must be validated into a bundle of separate national patents in selected countries before it can be enforced—the European patent itself cannot really be enforced. Most European patents are only validated in 3–5 states, rather than the whole of Europe. Though this will soon change when the unitary patent is adopted.

Comment: @Maca: Well, yes...it's complicated. But if you apply for a patent via the EPO now, you can ask for it to be a unitary patent as soon as they take effect (which will probably be before it issues). The agreements have all been signed, so as soon as the preparatory committee finishes their work, the Unified Patent Court will be established, and then unitary patents will be real (and yes, I'm sure you already know this as well, but onlookers probably don't).

Comment: @JerryCoffin - it’s six years later and no unitary European patent yet.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite: yeah--I (perhaps naively) thought it would happen fairly quickly at that time, but it's taking long enough that I did a bit of editing to (I hope) better reflect current reality.

Comment: Still not here - scheduled for spring of 2023